# Change logo app mobile in runtime with a image which is got from backend

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

I want change logo app mobile, which is built on react-native.

I've seen some ways to change logo app. But with that ways, i need to install all icon which i desire before building app.

My goal is to allow admins to change the app's logo with a new set of images that are not preconfigured.

Is there anyway to change logo app to an image which is got from backend, that wasn't existing while app was built ?

Comment: On iOS you can only set the app icon from the set of icons included in the app. This is a security measure to prevent apps from "pretending" to be Facebook or something after they have passed review. I don't know about Android but I suspect it has a a similar restriction.

Comment: @Paulw11 tks for your comment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.